# SpringMVC value of request parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm used to Java EE but not Spring MVC.  I've just created a new Spring MVC project and in the controller I have the following code generated.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());


        return "home";
    }

}
```

Normally, I would expect one of the parameters to be request and the other response, how do I find these values with Spring MVC?  For instance, I want to capture a username and password that will get sent here?  Is there something similar to a doGet and doPost method in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture parameters called `username` and `password`, then just declare them as method parameters:

```
public String login(Locale locale, Model model, String username, String password) {
```

Spring will supply them, or throw an exception if they're not present.

You could equally declare an `HttpServletRequest` parameter if you choose to:

```
public String login(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

But the first approach is cleaner.

Comment: You can also add @RequestParam annotation on each parameter if you wish to specify default values and required-flag.